# Digital Elevation Model resolution

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arc-hydro, flood

When I create flood areas using DEM in ArcGIS, which parameters do I consider to determine DEM's pixel size and resolution?

Answer (score 0):

DEM pixel size is based of your topographic map scale . DEM pixel size that calculate using topographic map with 1:25000 scale has 10 * 10 meters pixel size. For 1:50000 scale the pixel size must be 20*20 meters and so on.

consider the below links :

[What are appropriate pixel resolutions for DEMs based on source map scales?](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=371)

[Mathematical relationships among map scale, raster data resolution, and map display resolution](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/12/04/mathematical-relationships-among-map-scale-raster-data-resolution-and-map-display-resolution/)

Comment: I know that. But I think it is not only map scale.

Comment: please see the links .

Comment: Actually I see some studies used 7.5*7.5 pixel size. So, I thought map scale is not only  parameter for these studies.

Comment: @zeynep - pixel resolution is an irrelevant parameter and independent of raster resolution. When you export a map at HIGH resolution the raster contained with the exported output will have a HIGH pixel resolution.  As such you can export a 20cm resolution LiDAR DEM at letter size and 72DPI and the resulting file will have a low pixel resolution. Similarly, a coarse 30m resolution DEM exported to an ANSI E size and 300DPI will have a extremely high pixel resolution but it will not change that fact that the DEM will still be a 30m raster resolution.